# Error on LINQ query with sub query in left join

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I was trying to do a sub query inside a left join using LINQ, it looks like this, in SQL:

```
SELECT fields
FROM table1 A
LEFT JOIN table2 B ON B.Establishment = A.Establishment  
LEFT JOIN table3 C ON C.Vdb = B.Vdb AND C.Year = (SELECT MAX(Year) FROM table3 D WHERE D.Vdb = C.Vdb)
```

Using LINQ, I did the following:

```
var query = await (
    from a in _context.Table1
    
    join b in _context.Table2 on a.Establishment equals b.Establishment
    
    join c0 in _context.Table3 on b.Vdb equals c0.Vdb into gGroup
    from c in gGroup.Where(x => x.Year == (from c1 in _context.Table3
                                            where c1.Vdb == x.Vdb
                                            select c1.Year).Max()).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                            
    select new
    {
        fields
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

I built this code using LINQPad, so I was trying run there and everything was going fine, but when I put this code in my IDE and tried to run it I got the following error:

```
{
  "Message": "The LINQ expression (expression here) could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.",
  "ErrorName": "InvalidOperationException"
}
```

So I don't know exactly what's wrong so I can fix this, can anyone help me?

Comment: Which ORM Version? LINQ Pad may have never EF version.

Comment: Looking at the code it seems `.Max()` method could not translated to SQL,

Comment: I'm using .NET 5 and Entity Framework Core in 5.0.13 version.

Comment: Oh I see, you have used `GroupJoin` which has a lot of limitations in EF Core. It has no direct translation in the SQL, so rewrite query without using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GroupJoin` is almost non translatable by EF Core. Do not use this operator if you do not do simple LEFT JOIN.

I have rewritten query to use another technique which returns the same result:

```cs
var table3 = _context.Table3;

var latest = 
    from t in table3.Select(t => new { t.Vdb }).Distinct()
    from r in table3
      .Where(r => r.Vdb == t.Vdb)
      .OrderByDescending(r.Year)
      .Take(1)
    select r;

var query = 
    from a in _context.Table1
    join b in _context.Table2 on a.Establishment equals b.Establishment into gb
    from b in gb.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join c in latest on b.Vdb equals c.Vdb into gc
    from c in gc.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        // fields
    };
```